# Saving a particular variable value locally entered in a form of webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I save a variable value(if possible in notepad of my computer or some where locally in my pc) entered in a form in a webpage when a particular button with given id is clicked on the webpage using javascript.

Here is the HTML code for it (and the variable value to be saved  is pass.value in javascript)-

```
<input id="pass" class="inputtext" type="abc" name="pass">
</input>
```

Comment: JavaScript can't interact with files on the client computer.

Comment: Submit the form to your server and let the server save the contents to your filesystem. Passwords should be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage or cookie to store some data between page.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

If you want store data only in one page use javascript variable

Comment: Thanks! links were very useful

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is possible. Even if I would reccommend NOT doing this, because this is pretty dirty code. But if you insist, here is how I would do it:

Add a onchange-function to your input field:

```
<input id="pass" class="inputtext" type="abc" name="pass" onchange="savePass()">
</input>
```

Use the following javascript function:

```
function savePass() {
   pass = document.getElementById('pass').value
    uriContent = "data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(pass);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
        document.body.appendChild(link); 
        link.download = "filename.txt";
        link.href = uriContent;
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link); 
    } else {
        location.replace(uri);
    }
}
```

This actually creates a "download"-link, activates it by simulating a user click action, and then removes the link again after download is initiated.

Depending on your actual need, cookies is very possibly the right way to do this though.